# Bounty 25 or 50?

Tags: support

My [bounty was auto-awarded](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/what-else-is-involved-in-silicon-based-life) and one answer shows a (+25) badge. But the bounty was for 50 points. What's going on?

Also, how did it choose, since it's not the highest scoring post nor a new post.

Answer (score 1):

1. [An auto awarded bounty is only given half of the reputation.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded **half the bounty amount**. If two or
>   more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the
>   oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria,
>   no bounty is awarded to anyone.

2. Do you remember the exact moment when you created the bounty? It was the 26 of may and only one answer was posted after that moment.

> the highest voted answer created **after the bounty started** with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Comment: Splitting it between two answers would be great, anyway, ans I was thinking I would award one and create a second bounty to award the second. But now I see that the bounty amounts *start* at 100, and I can't award another 25 or even 50. What's the deal?

Comment: @JDługosz  From the same source:  "Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on)."